# Скрипт от Laravel при загрузке PDF файла теряется его название

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, vue.js, pdf

Всем привет!

Установил скрипт от Laravel и поскольку в php еще не силен, не могу найти и устранить один косячек.

Дело в том что на сайте есть функция для загрузки и отправки резюме. Она работает, файл PDF отправляется и доходит получателя. Но почему то теряется его название.
К примеру до отправки файл называется resume.pdf но как только он загрузился в мою панель управления на сайте, или был отправлен получателю, то название его меняется на, "skmdo3453942294593.pdf" такую вот абракадабру. Что можно сделать, где копать я к сожалению не знаю.

Может кто сталкивался с подобным?!

Могу предоставить код или что нужно, только дайте знать.

Спасибо

```
<?php
// From Company's Form
$classLeftCol = 'col-sm-3';
$classRightCol = 'col-sm-9';

if (isset($originForm)) {
    // From User's Form
    if ($originForm == 'user') {
        $classLeftCol = 'col-md-3';
        $classRightCol = 'col-md-7';
    }

    // From Post's Form
    if ($originForm == 'post') {
        $classLeftCol = 'col-md-3';
        $classRightCol = 'col-md-8';
    }
} else {
    // Required var
    $originForm = null;
}
?>
<div id="resumeFields">

    @if ($originForm != 'message')
        @if (isset($resume) and !empty($resume))
            <!-- name -->
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (isset($errors) and $errors->has('resume.name')) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label class="{{ $classLeftCol }} control-label" for="resume.name">{{ t('Name') }}</label>
                <div class="{{ $classRightCol }}">
                    <input name="resume[name]"
                           placeholder="{{ t('Name') }}"
                           class="form-control input-md"
                           type="text"
                           value="{{ old('resume.name', (isset($resume->name) ? $resume->name : '')) }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif

        <!-- filename -->
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (isset($errors) and $errors->has('resume.filename')) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label class="{{ $classLeftCol }} control-label" for="resume.filename"> {{ t('Your resume') }} </label>
            <div class="{{ $classRightCol }}">
                <div class="mb10">
                    <input id="resumeFilename" name="resume[filename]" type="file" class="file">
                </div>
                <p class="help-block">{{ t('File types: :file_types', ['file_types' => showValidFileTypes('file')]) }}</p>
                @if (isset($resume))
                    @if (!empty($resume) and !empty($resume->filename) and \Storage::exists($resume->filename))
                    <div>
                        <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ \Storage::url($resume->filename) }}" target="_blank">
                            <i class="icon-attach-2"></i> {{ t('Download current Resume') }}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    @endif
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    @else
        <!-- filename -->
        <div {!! (config('lang.direction')=='rtl') ? 'dir="rtl"' : '' !!} class="form-group required <?php echo (isset($errors) and $errors->has('resume.filename')) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label for="resume.filename" class="control-label">{{ t('Resume File') }} </label>
            <input id="resumeFilename" name="resume[filename]" type="file" class="file">
            <p class="help-block">{{ t('File types: :file_types', ['file_types' => showValidFileTypes('file')]) }}</p>
            @if (!empty($resume) and \Storage::exists($resume->filename))
                <div>
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ \Storage::url($resume->filename) }}" target="_blank">
                        <i class="icon-attach-2"></i> {{ t('Download current Resume') }}
                    </a>
                </div>
            @endif
        </div>
    @endif

</div>

@section('after_styles')
    @parent
    <style>
        #resumeFields .select2-container {
            width: 100% !important;
        }
    </style>
@endsection

@section('after_scripts')
    @parent
    <script>
        /* Initialize with defaults (resume) */
        $('#resumeFilename').fileinput(
        {
            language: '{{ config('app.locale') }}',
            @if (config('lang.direction') == 'rtl')
                rtl: true,
            @endif
            showPreview: false,
            allowedFileExtensions: {!! getUploadFileTypes('file', true) !!},
            showUpload: false,
            showRemove: false,
            maxFileSize: {{ (int)config('settings.upload.max_file_size', 1500) }}
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Я так подозреваю это делается намеренно, чтобы при загрузке двух файлов с одинаковыми именами они не затирали друг друга у вас на сервере, куда эти резюме складываются. Чтобы вам выдавалось верное наименование файла, надо чтобы у вас где то оно хранилось и уже при скачивании или пересылке файла подставлялось нужное наименование. Но в любом случае вам нужно будет изучить и поправить код.

Comment: Понятно, а какой код именно нужно править? JS или PHP?

Comment: сервер - это php

Comment: Понятно, а выше мной указанном коде нельзя прописать какую нибудь функцию? Что то вроде сохранить родное название файла при его загрузке. Или может у кого статейка найдется как это можно сделать? Буду сказать мерси за любую помощь! И вроде самому интересно разобраться, но не могу найти информации как! :(